# C++ function hidden by function with same name in another DLL

Tags: c++

I've got C++ code separated into 2 libraries (DLLs) and each library has a function w/ the same name, although each is in a different namespace.  So in library 1, I have something like the following.

```
namespace LibOne
{
   void Foo(ClassOne& src); 
}
```

In library 2, I have classes that were accessing LibOne::Foo w/o a problem as follows.

```
using namespace LibOne;
namespace LibTwo
{
    class MyClass
    {
        ...
        void MyFunc()
        {
            Foo(src);
        }
    }

}
```

Then in library 2, I added additional functions w/ the same name.

```
namespace LibTwo
{
   void Foo(ClassTwo& src); 
   void Foo(ClassThree& src); 
}
```

Now the usage of LibOne::Foo, issues a compiler error

```
error C2665: 'LibOne::Foo': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

I can resolve the error by changing my code as follows to specify the full name of the function, but I'm just trying to understand why the addition of the function in LibTwo appears to hide the versions of the function from LibOne?  Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

```
LibOne::Foo(src)
```

Comment: Present your [mcve].

Comment: Problem is how yo use `Foo` (kind of argument) and libraries structure has nothing to this error.

Comment: Not really enough of the code snippets to reproduce the problem, without making some speculative assumptions.  A [mcve] would be helpful.  There are not very many situations that a `using namespace` are reasonably good ones to use it.  ADL is not always your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only the innermost scope that contains a name will be examined. There is `Foo` in namespace `LibTwo`, so the compiler doesn't even notice there's also a `Foo` imported into the global namespace.

In general, avoid `using namespace`, and prefer to explicitly qualify names. `LibOne::Foo`